# Flex: Disable range on Slider?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex3

I have an HSlider with a minimum of 1 and a maximum of 6. Is there a way I can disable the range 3 - 6, so the user can only select from the range 1-3 on the slider.

Note: Your first thought might be to tell me to set the maximum to 3. I dont want to change the maximum to 3, I want the user to know there is more, but currently not selectable.

Thanks!!

Comment: Michael's suggestion below is the best solution.  Shouldn't be too hard either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to override the `getValueFromX` method in [`Slider`](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/sliderClasses/Slider.html).  It's marked `mx_internal`, so you'll need to add the necessary [import and use statements](http://codeofdoom.com/wordpress/2009/03/12/when-and-how-to-use-mx_internal-in-flex/).

As with the Event.CHANGE suggestion, it won't show a disabled UI for the remainder of the track, which would be ideal.  For that you'll need to override more of Slider or draw your own component.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener for the CHANGE event. When it sees that the new slider position is greater than 3, you can reset the slider to 3.